# What are the protrusions on the outside of the Falcon 9 nose fairing?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fairings

Near the base of the Falcon 9 nose fairing is an array of square protrusions (marked in red) that you'd probably want to avoid unless they serve a very essential purpose. Does anyone know what that purpose might be?

[image]

My first thought was these protrusions are cold gas thrusters, but this arrangement would seem overkill, since the first stage uses only two diametrically opposed pods (instead of the circular array seen in the picture).

The blue marker highlights another protrusion that more closely resembles the cold gas thruster pods of the first stage. Can anyone say for sure if that's correct?

Comment: Pressure vents.  They start covered with paper/plastic that blows off.